# The most frequent range of numbers in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I know there are lot of topics about "The Most frequent Number in an array"

But I'm looking for code that can show me the most frequent range of numbers in an array. I couldn't find any topic about that tho.

Lets say there is an array with these values { 1 ,2 ,2 ,5 ,8 ,8 ,9 ,10} and the range is +-1...
 most frequent range of numbers would be 8-10.

Is this possible? Can anyone help please?

Comment: What is the time constraint? How big can the array be? What numbers can be inside the array?

Comment: *"But I'm looking for code"* - that alone makes this question off-topic. This isn't a code service. The task presented is certainly *possible*, and likely even a formidable task to undertake, but I can assure you no one here will do so until you at least *try* to. And, if/when you get stuck, bring *specific* questions about how you tried to solve this, debug this, and where things seem to be going wrong. If your question is about the *algorithm*, it's not about finding code, and you should update your question.

Comment: I don't understand.  In your example of {1,2,2,5,8,8,9,10}, the number 2 is as frequent as 8.  How did you determine the range as 8-10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate through your values array, and for each value `v`, increase the count for the specific value `v` as well as for the values +/- 1, i.e. for `v-1` and for `v+1`. Then, find the value with the highest count, let's call this value `v_maxcount`; the range is then `v_maxcount -1 .. v_maxcount + 1`.

Comment: May not be the most efficient solution, but it's stupidly easy to write with a `std::map<int,int>` keeping track of the frequency counts.  I'd start here and profile it to see if it meets the required performance targets.